# How to use an Angular component as a div

Tags: angular

I want to make a "popup" component which is just a wrapper for any other components i add inside of it. For clerification this is how i want to use it:

```
<app-popup>
    <some-component></some-component>
</app-popup>
```

Then it would just load the "some-component" centered inside of the "app-popup" component.

The example is also exactly how i tried it, just made my popup component like this:

html:

```
<div class="popup-wrapper"></div>
```

css:

```
.popup-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to just work...

Is it possible to use a component in that way?

Comment: I think you can use angular's content projection technique.
[Read here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add css class to app-popup component and then inside component's template use *ng-content* tag